# Can optaplanner facts be arrays?

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I'm looking to load a large number of facts, 3 million distances between points, and I want to know whether optaplanner facts can be provided using a searchable data structure such as an Array.  My sense is that using a List to hold that many values would create long search times.  I'm using Drools scoring.

Comment: I am working on a example with 100k points and realistic distances between them. Problem is that keeping all distances (100k)² is impossible because a 2D array of (20k)² 32bit ints takes almost 2GB of RAM memory (in any language, not just in java).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, problem facts can be arrays. Problem facts can also have fields that are arrays. To use them in the Drools score calculation, you need to return them from the `getProblemFacts()` method as a `Collection`, but just wrap them in an `ArrayList`, you will not suffer any noticable perf slowdown there: it's a 1 time hit at initialization and as soon as they are in the Drools `workingMemory`, that getProblemFacts() Collection is forgotten.

Note that `ArrayList` (which implements the interface `List` which in turn implements `Collection`) has the same memory and performance scalability characteristics of an array. What I mean by that is that it does have some overhead, but not BigO affecting overhead.
Also note that it's highly recommended to use `new ArrayList(int initialCapacity)` over the no-arg constructor if you have any estimation of the size you'll need.

Planning entities currently need to be a Collection because `@PlanningEntityCollectionProperty` currently only supports a return type of `Collection`. Feel free to make a jira that we also should support an array - or even contribute a github PR that implements it :)

Planning value ranges currently need to be a `List` or numeric bounds. Feel free to make a jira or PR that we also should support an array there, it's just a matter of copy-pasting `ListValueRange` to `ArrayValueRange`.